# Dell Inspiron 1525 - Internal hard disk drive not found

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I have a Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop and every now and then it is shut down for no reason with this message on the screen:

> internal hard disk drive not found
>   To resolve this issue, try to reseat the drive.
>
> No bootable devices--strike F1 to retry boot, F2 for setup utility
>   Press F5 to run onboard diagnostics.

If I just restart the computer it will boot up without problems. This happens about twice a day and it looks like it only happens when the computer has been idle for a few minutes.

I have already tried to reseated the drive, ran the onboard diagnostics and there were no errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried reseating the drive?

Comment: It happened to my inspirin 1525. I contacted Dell and they said directly that its a hardware failure. As mine was not under warranty i had to buy another Harddisk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution. The problem was caused by the Broadcom Wireless Network Adapter in my Dell Inspiron 1525.

Here's what I did:

1. Start
2. Control Panel
3. Device Manager
4. Expand "Network adapters"
5. Double-click "Broadcom 802.11g Network Adapter"
6. Click "Advanced"
7. Select "Wake-Up Mode" from the list
8. Change the value to "None"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of 2 possibilities:

1. Your HD is about to crock - make sure you have a full backup of your valuables. To test this, try putting in a different HD (if you have one).
2. The SATA (it is SATA on the 1525, not IDE, right?) connector has a broken contact or another problem. Again, this can be verified with another HD.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some tests and figured that this only happens when the computer goes to sleep or hibernates. This is probably not related to the HD.

When I hit the sleep button in Windows the computer looks like it's going into Sleep mode but a few seconds later it's restarted, and stops with the error message above.

The computer is running Windows Vista (SP2) and I have installed all available Windows Updates and the latest manufacturer drivers.

I have changed the power settings for all devices where it's available so that they are not allowed to wake up the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with my Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop while changing the hard drive to a new one – it'd say

> internal hard disk drive not found

To resolve this issue, try reseating the drive.

I think the new hard drive seems a little slimmer, so before putting the new hard drive in the slot you should press the board were the SATA hard drive connects, and then push the hard drive in slowly until it connects.