# Dell Inspiron 1525 - No boot sector on HDD

Tags: hard-drive, dell-inspiron, boot

> No boot sector in internal Hard disk.
>   No bootable devices - strike F1 to retry boot, F2 for setup utility
>   Press F5 to run on board diagnostics.

My Dell Inspiron 1525 doesn't boot at all. During start-up, I get the above error message each time. I've already phoned Dell and they told me to replace the drive with a new one. SU and some other tech forums also support this. So, I've replaced the HDD. Still, I get the same error.

I have a thought that my BIOS doesn't recognize my HD still. I've already checked the setup utility. Then, I used my XP CD to install a new copy. The boot sequence has the DVD-RW at the top followed by HD. But sadly, It doesn't recognize the CD too. Then, I made a bootable USB using WinToFlash and now, it doesn't recognize the USB too. What would be the case?

Do I have to replace my new HD too?

**Note:** My question is probably related to this one already been asked here - [Dell Inspiron 1525 - Internal hard disk drive not found](https://superuser.com/q/103225). But, the answer wasn't helpful to me. I mean, it didn't work for mine...

Comment: Have you selected F5 to try thge diagnostics?  Possible Motherboard issue so F5 would be a good start.  Failing that, a bootable diagnostic tool would help.  Many forums outline the process.  One her http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/18193950.aspx

Comment: @DaveM: Hi Dave. Yeah... That *thing* ran for nearly 40 mins. It was of no use. Thanks for your link. I'll check that out :-)

Comment: @Ramhound: Hi Ramhound. Yes. It isn't. And that's my irritating problem :-)

Comment: What happens when you look at the disk with diskpart or fdisk. Does it have a bootsector? (If not fdisk /mbr should rewrite one).